# Is the notion of 'no-effect' flawed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, effect-size, large-data

I am a student of mathematics, but my knowledge of probability and statistics is rather limited. So please forgive if this is a bad question.

T-tests are a popular way to perform statistical inference. However the null-hypothesis of 'no-effect' seems flawed. Take any two variables: suppose they're 'amount of time person spent on cross-validated in 2012' and 'extent to which person likes ice-cream in 2013' and you'll most likely see an effect, as long as your sample size is enormous. At worst, you can regard the whole population as a single sample, in which case there is no uncertainty:, thus if you see a positive relationship you can reject the 'no effect' hypothesis and if you see a negative relationship you can also reject the 'no effect' hypothesis. So either way, the null-hypothesis is rejected.

*Therefore, we can reject the null-hypothesis without collecting any data.*

Is the notion of 'no effect' fundamentally flawed, or have I made a logical error?

Of course you may say, "that's why we also report effect sizes," but that's kind of missing the point. If the concept of 'no effect' is flawed this badly, then we should forget this 'no-effect' business and use more sensible hypotheses.

Comment: Almost all null hypotheses are (pretty obviously) false. But it's a bit like a footrace where even after examining the pictures in the photo-finish you *still* can't discern a difference. You might *logically* know that some single individual *must* have won, but you have no basis on which to award one of them first prize. You can't separate them; it's a draw.

Comment: This is why *effect size* is so important. Hypothesis testing on its own is often meaningless. You may want to check out equivalence testing, too.

Comment: Is there a list of examples where pure nil-null hypothesis testing is unambiguously fully adequate?
Gelman gives one example here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/pvalues3.pdf

Comment: You could be interestid in this paper http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~jiashun/Teaching/F08STAT756/Lectures/Efron.pdf  by Efron where he introduces the concept of *empirical null hypothesis*